# XmlReader loop through node

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing, xml-parsing, xmlreader

Hey all i have the following code:

```
    Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(xmlString))
        reader.ReadToFollowing("GridChannel")
        Dim Channel As String = reader.GetAttribute("Channel")
        Dim DisplayName As String = reader.GetAttribute("DisplayName")

        reader.ReadToFollowing("Airings")
        reader.ReadToFollowing("GridAiring")

        Dim Title As String = reader.GetAttribute("Title")
        Dim EpisodeTitle As String = reader.GetAttribute("EpisodeTitle")
        Dim AiringTDurationime As String = reader.GetAttribute("AiringTDurationime")
        Dim isHD As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetAttribute("isHD"))
        Dim TVRating As String = reader.GetAttribute("TVRating")
    End Using
```

That code works just fine above but i am having problems with looping through the **Airings** part.

The XML for that part looks like this:

```
    <Airings>
        <GridAiring ProgramId="35951" SeriesId="3490" Title="Matlock" EpisodeTitle="Santa Claus" AiringTime="2013-04-12T14:00:00Z" Duration="60" Color="Color" AiringType="Unknown" CC="true" LetterBox="false" Stereo="false" HD="false" SAP="false" TVRating="TV-PG" Dolby="false" DSS="false" HDLevel="HD Level Unknown" DVS="false" Category="Other" Subcategory="drama" Sports="false"/>
        <GridAiring ProgramId="828869" SeriesId="1409" Title="In the Heat of the Night" EpisodeTitle="Hatton's Turn" AiringTime="2013-04-12T15:00:00Z" Duration="60" Color="Color" AiringType="Unknown" CC="true" LetterBox="false" Stereo="false" HD="false" SAP="false" TVRating="TV-PG@V" Dolby="false" DSS="false" HDLevel="HD Level Unknown" DVS="false" Category="Other" Subcategory="crime drama" Sports="false"/>
        <GridAiring ProgramId="978338" SeriesId="1409" Title="In the Heat of the Night" EpisodeTitle="Hatton's Turn" AiringTime="2013-04-12T16:00:00Z" Duration="60" Color="Color" AiringType="Unknown" CC="true" LetterBox="false" Stereo="false" HD="false" SAP="false" TVRating="TV-PG@V" Dolby="false" DSS="false" HDLevel="HD Level Unknown" DVS="false" Category="Other" Subcategory="crime drama" Sports="false"/>
        <GridAiring ProgramId="4210626" Title="WGN Midday News" AiringTime="2013-04-12T17:00:00Z" Duration="60" Color="Color" AiringType="New" CC="true" LetterBox="false" Stereo="true" HD="false" SAP="false" TVRating="None" Dolby="false" DSS="false" HDLevel="HD Level Unknown" DVS="false" Category="News" Subcategory="newscast" Sports="false"/>
        <GridAiring ProgramId="878716" SeriesId="1028666" Title="Walker, Texas Ranger" EpisodeTitle="El Coyote, Part 2" AiringTime="2013-04-12T18:00:00Z" Duration="60" Color="Color" AiringType="Unknown" CC="true" LetterBox="false" Stereo="true" HD="false" SAP="false" TVRating="TV-14@V" Dolby="false" DSS="false" HDLevel="HD Level Unknown" DVS="false" Category="Other" Subcategory="crime drama" Sports="false"/>
    </Airings>
```

Comment: Agreed.  Do you *need* to use `XmlReader`?

Comment: @StevenDoggart No i do not but that was the best example i found to do it with. Feel free to show me a better way?

Comment: If you need to load all of the data in an XML document, I would recommend using the `XmlSerializer` class to deserialize the document into an object that matches the document structure.  If you only need to load certain parts of the document, then I would recommend using either `XmlDocument` with XPath or `XDocument` with LINQ.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Updated my OP here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok to loop you do this:

```
While reader.ReadToFollowing("GridAiring")
    Dim Title As String = reader.GetAttribute("Title")
    Dim EpisodeTitle As String = reader.GetAttribute("EpisodeTitle")
    Dim AiringTDurationime As String = reader.GetAttribute("AiringTDurationime")
    Dim isHD As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetAttribute("isHD"))
    Dim TVRating As String = reader.GetAttribute("TVRating")
End While
```

Answer (score 2):

Without going into XML serialization, why not use [XmlReader.GetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxy2cd1w.aspx)?

You should then be able to shrink your code down to this:

```vb
Dim ServiceId As String = reader.GetAttribute("ServiceId")
```

and so on, which is much more readable, and easier to maintain.

**EDIT:** to loop through an XML, I prefer this way:

```vb
Dim Airings As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)
For Each GridAiring As XElement In Airings.Root.Elements
  Dim ProgramId As String = GridAiring.Attribute("ProgramId").Value
  'read other properties here
Next
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, though, is it? :)

Comment: Because it doesn't answer his actual question which was how to read the `Airings` element.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: See my update. Does it count as an answer now?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping through, you would get better performance with LINQ. Here is an example pulling the ProgramId, SeriesId and Title into an enumerable.

```
Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load("c:\tmp\test.xml")
Dim airings = From i In document.Descendants("Airings")
              Select New With
                     {Key .ProgramId = i.Attribute("ProgramId").Value,
                      Key .SeriesId = i.Attribute("SeriesId").Value,
                      Key .Title = i.Attribute("Title").Value}
```

You could then loop through the enumerable. A small example just printing the results in a console

```
For Each a In airings
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", a.ProgramId, a.SeriesId, a.Title))
    Console.Read()
Next
```

The idea ofcourse being for each item you can just call `.ProgramId`, `.SeriesId` etc to get the value

If you wanted to add checking to be sure the Airing does not have a a missing attribute and prevent possible exceptions, you could add checks in the select to be sure it exists as below.

```
Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load("c:\tmp\test.xml")
Dim airings = From i In document.Descendants("Airings")
              Where i.Attribute("ProgramId") IsNot Nothing _
              And i.Attribute("SeriesId") IsNot Nothing _
              And i.Attribute("Title") IsNot Nothing
              Select New With
                     {Key .ProgramId = i.Attribute("ProgramId").Value,
                      Key .SeriesId = i.Attribute("SeriesId").Value,
                      Key .Title = i.Attribute("Title").Value}
```